How to add SQLTableSchema into chromadb llama-index?
In the code below I need to add one more data into chromadb. How could I do that?
from llama_index.core import SQLDatabase
    from llama_index.core.objects import (
        SQLTableNodeMapping,
        ObjectIndex,
        SQLTableSchema,
    )
    # chroma db
    import chromadb
    from llama_index.vector_stores.chroma import ChromaVectorStore
    from llama_index.core import StorageContext, VectorStoreIndex

    sql_database = SQLDatabase(engine)

    table_schema_objs = [
        SQLTableSchema(table_name=t.table_name, context_str=t.table_summary +"\n Given below are the column Details:\n" + 
        "\n".join([f"Column name: {col.column_name} with description: {col.column_description}" for     col in t.columns]))
        for t in table_infos
    ]  # add a SQLTableSchema for each table

    print("Creating chromadb", chroma_path)
    # create and save chroma
    db = chromadb.PersistentClient(path=chroma_path)

    chroma_collection = db.get_or_create_collection("table_schema")
    vector_store = ChromaVectorStore(chroma_collection=chroma_collection)
    storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)
    object_index = ObjectIndex.from_objects(
        table_schema_objs,
        table_node_mapping,
        storage_context=storage_context)

    obj_retriever = object_index.as_retriever(similarity_top_k=3)

I've gone through this article and done what it says but it is not working.
https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/chromadb-tutorial-step-by-step-guide
collection.add(
    documents = [student_info, club_info, university_info],
    metadatas = [{"source": "student info"},{"source": "club info"},{'source':'university info'}],
    ids = ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
)

